# oak chair remains sticky after using formbys refininisher

Tags: furniture, hardwood-refinishing

I am refinishing an oak chair, after using formby's refinisher, 90% of the chair is smooth and clean, however, the back slats (in this case, round) are still sticky to the touch.  I have cleaned and cleaned and used steel wool and a tacky cloth after, however they remain sticky.  any ideas.  thanks

Answer (score 1):

Different wood will dry at different rates.   So if you're touching a dry part and concluding "something must be wrong since it's not all dry", just wait.

I would not muss with any painted surface which is still tacky, unless you want the mussing material permanently embedded in the coating.

There are some additives you can add to oil-based coatings to make them dry faster.

It also helps to remove humidity, so if you're in a very muggy area (e.g. Florida or Ohio), consider putting it in a room with a dehumidifier.  Don't blast the dehumidifier straight at it, or you'll stick a bunch of dust to it.

If you want to hasten drying, try putting the item in your car (put down some plastic first) and leave the car out in the sun.  As you know from tragic stories about babies and dogs, car interiors get *rather warm* in the direct sun. If you don't want it to get to 160F, crack a window or two.  This will make your car smell funny for a day.

Keep in mind also: *Curing* is not the same thing as *drying*.  Dry means tack-free.  Cured means the coating has *polymerized* and reached full strength.  Most paints have a vulnerable time when they are tack-free, but hardly begun their cure.   I once sat in a "tack free" chair only to get up and find my denim pattern imprinted on the "tack free" surface.